# Why can't I raise the priority level in 12.04 in gnome-system-monitor

Tags: system-monitor

When I go to raise a priority level it displays this

[image]

I know it says permission denied, but is this a bug? **I can lower it but not raise it.** Is this normal?

**EDIT: I think this might be a bug, because the only limitation is states in the help value is you can't set it to something less than 0, but I'm not sure if doing something else wrong**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running as a normal user, this is normal.  You can only raise priorities as a super user.

Comment: Cool :-) I was worried I was doing something wrong. Thanks